# openSUSE 12.1 x64: VNC presents "nobody's X11 desktop"

Tags: opensuse, vnc, yast

I activated VNC using Yast and it works but it only display's "nobody's X11 desktop".

I use Apple Remote Desktop to connect and gave it username and password. I also tried with Chicken of the VNC which does not take a username but only a password and it cannot connect at all. Port number is always correct (5901).

What's wrong?